# Simpson's index

Tags: ecology

Simpson’s index is a diversity index which is the summation of the square of the probabilities of the species in a community.

[image]

The value varies between 0-1.

here, p<sub>i</sub>=n/N where n<sub>i</sub>=number of individual of species i in the community and N=total no. of individuals.

S=total number of species.

It is the measure that equals the probability that two individuals taken at random from a community belongs to the same species.The probability decreases if the species richness and evenness increase. **It is strongly influenced by the most abundant species.**

From:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_index)
- Fundamentals of ecology, Odum
- [Biodiversity of fungi](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Tr9joZRnZIsC&pg=PA64&dq=Shannon%20diversity%20index&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6hsyf_drRAhUMuo8KHT7-DN4Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=Shannon%20diversity%20index&f=false)

What is meant by 'It is strongly influenced by the most abundant species'?

Comment: I'm assuming that term is meant as a critique/limitation or at least a point to note when taking the index as a measure of diversity. They just mean that the value for D in that equation is affected strongly by how abundant the most abundant species is. So, if you have one species that is very abundant, you might get a high value for D (=low diversity, strangely) even if there are hundreds of other, less abundant species, because adding 1 more species with low abundance does little to the measure.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know whether this math will be clarifying forr you, but it might help you understand why "*It is strongly influenced by the most abundant species.*" It is all about finding the best *p*'s that does the minimization for $D$. You can skip to conclusion if you feel like skipping all the math.

You want to find the critical point (where the function attains its minimum and maximum) of:

$$D = p_{1}^2+p_{2}^2+...+p_{n}^2$$

given ${p_{1}+p_{2}+...+p_{n}=1}$, for $p_{i}$ of species.

[Lagrange Multiplier method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) is one of the techniques to find the values given to $p_{1}, p_{2}, ...p_{n}$ to make $p_{1}^2+p_{2}^2+...+p_{n}^2$  go to maximum or minimum given some constraint on this.

Assume:

$$f = p_{1}^2+p_{2}^2+...+p_{n}^2$$ 
$$g = p_{1}+p_{2}+...p_{n}$$

According to Lagrange multiplier:

$$\partial_{p_{1},..p_{n}} f = \lambda \partial_{p_{1},..p_{n}} g$$

We have to find the value of $\lambda$.

So after partial fractions step, we will end up with these equations:

$$np_{1} = \lambda ; np_{2} = \lambda;  ... np_{n} = \lambda$$

and we already know that $p_{1}+p_{2}+...+p_{n} = 1$

From above, we know that:

$$p_{1} = p_{2} = ... = p_{n} = \lambda/n$$ we get $\lambda = 2/n$ and from this the minimum values of the function:

$$f = D =  p_{1}^2+p_{2}^2+...+p_{n}^2$$

is when all $p_{i} = 1/n $ for i is denoting each species in ${1,...,n}$

**Conclusion**:
So $D$ value attains its minimum when all terms $p_{i}$ are equal. As any value goes away from $1/n$ ('n' is the total number of individuals of species you got)the value increases drastically as it is being squared in $D$.

Sample example will be like $0.5^2 + 0.5^2 = 0.25$ but a change from this say $0.6,0.4$ increases $0.5$ term by $0.11$ but decreases $0.4$ term by only $0.09$.

Hope this helps.